# Adding data labels to boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, coercion

Here's my code:

```
iFacVector <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,12,9,9,1,10,12,1,9,5))

iTargetVector <- c(2,1,0,1,6,9,15,1,8,0,1,2,1,1,9,12,1)

bp <- plot(iFacVector,iTargetVector)
text(bp,tapply(iTargetVector,iFacVector,median),labels=tapply(iTargetVector,iFacVector,median),cex=.8)
```

I am getting the following (classic R) error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, recycle = TRUE) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

The vectors I am passing are numeric so I don't know what the problem is.  I have tried `unlist()` and `as.vector()`.  I have also tried using `bp$stats[3,]` as the labels.

Comment: Just remove `bp,` from your `text` statement.  You might also want to add `pos=3`

Comment: But why?  I am doing the exact same thing with a barplot earlier in my script?  Doesn't text() need to know which object it is referencing?

Comment: No,  in Base R graphics,  it will write the text to the _current_ graphics device. Try it! :-)

Comment: Sure, I knew that.  I just got another code sample to work, referencing the plot as the first argument to text().

Comment: For example, try this code:

iFacVector <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,12,9,9,1,10,12,1,9,5))

iTargetVector <- c(2,1,0,1,6,9,15,1,8,0,1,2,1,1,9,12,1)

bp <- barplot(table(iFacVector),main=paste0(iFacColName," Histogram"))
bpLabel <- table(iFacVector)
labelFactor <- ifelse(min(bpLabel)<10,.8,.9)
text(bp,bpLabel*labelFactor,labels=bpLabel,cex=.8)

First, with "bp" as first argument, and then without it.

Comment: When I try your code with bp, I get no labels at all. Without bp, I get poorly placed labels.

Comment: I think I get it.  The bp is actually the x coordinate.  Somehow, calling the plot provides the appropriate breaks.  Thanks!  Make your comment the answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `text` gives the arguments as

> text(x, ...)

so the first argument in your code,  bp, is being treated as the x coordinate for where to place the text. You can just leave off the bp and get better behavior. You might also want to add `pos=3` to get a nicer placement of the text.